# How to document existing Selenium Webdriver tests?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am in charge of testing of a web application using Selenium Webdriver with Python. Over the past year I created a large script (20K+ lines) where each test is a separate function. Now my boss wants me to document my tests explaining in plan English what each test does. What tool would you recommend to document the steps your tests make?

Comment: I don't know exactly how your documentation should looks like, but you can try [Sphinx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx) - cool tool for documentation generation

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great question. Many people and companies don't bother managing their existing tests properly which leads to redundant and repeated code without having a clear idea what **is** covered by automated tests.

There is no single answer to this question but in general you can consider the following options:

- Testing framework built in reporting. In Java, for example, you have the unit testing libraries like `jUnit` and `TestNG`. When they run, they generate certain output that can later be formatted and reviewed as the need arises. I am sure there an implementation of unit testing framework like this in Python too.
- You can also consider using a BDD tool like Cucumber. This is a bit different and might not be suitable in certain cases when the tests are low level system checks. It can however help you organize your test scenarios and keep them an a readable form. It is also very good for reporting to a non-technical person.